# How to get user information in Spring Security SAML Sample(ECP profile)

Tags: spring-saml

Currently, I'm using spring-security-saml2-sample project(V1.0.1) as an SP, and Shibboleth as an IdP. I've implemented the Web SSO profile and trying to write an ECP client to make ECP profile work. However, I found limited documents about ECP profile in spring security saml(Ref doc Chapter 10.4)..

I found two useful ECP client samples in github:

github.com/spaetow/ShibbolethECPAuthClient

github.com/DARIAH-DE/shib-http-client

After enabling PAOS binding and "ecpEnabled" in SP's metadata generator, I wrote some sample ECP client code refering to the above two project, the main flow is:

1. Send a Get request to "localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/login" with PAOS related header.
2. Get the response(SAML Request) and generate a SAML Envelope.
3. Use the new generated SAML Envelope to Post to Shibboleth IdP(https://exampleIDP/idp/profile/SAML2/SOAP/ECP), with UserName/Password in Authorization Header(basic authentication).
4. Shibboleth authenticate and response with SAML Assertion(Also an SAML Envelope).
5. Send the SAML Assertion(Envelope) to SP: "localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SSO" and get response.

I think I've succeeded in the first four steps, Shibboleth can authenticate the user and send the SAML Response. But I've got some problems in the 5th step. And even some examples end in step 4.

I found that, spring security saml gets the 5th request and tries to Authenticate the SAML response just like WebSSO profile does. The logic is in "org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter". After parse the saml response and get the Authentication, the response will be redirect to a default target URL"/". The logic is in AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.handle(req,resp,authn). So, I can only get an 302 HTTP response in the ECP client.

Here are my questions:

1. I want to get user information in the 5th step, do I have to write another filter instead of "SAMLProcessingFilter" to send the Authentication as response? Or is there any other ways(I think ECP client cannot parse SAML Assertion received in Step 4)?
2. In this situation, my ECP client likes "Rest client" very much, because I have not record any cookies in my code. So after the 5th step(after login), how can I access the SP again for another resource? Does that mean I have to record the JSessionID cookie in the ECP client?
3. Is the theory of SAML SSO(WebSSO) like Jasig CAS(Use cookie/session)? If so, in the ECP mode, How can I single sign on two ECP clients(each connect to different SP but SP cpnnect to the same IdP). Or, can I make SSO in a ECP client and a browser?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there something special about step 5 in which implementing a SAMLUserDetails service does not work for you?

Comment: @slambeth  Nothing special.The problem is, I can only get a HTTP 302 response in the 5th step. The bean named "successRedirectHandler" will redirect the http requst. Recently, I implemented a class implementing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler to return Authentication directly.